# Group m groups with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that replaces the letter n with (\w{1,}) -- meaning any word can stand in for the letter n. Now I want to make a group out of m instances of (\w{1,}) -- i.e add parens around m instances of `(\w{1,})`, like this:

```
"(" + "(\w{1,}), (\w{1,}), (\w{1,}) .... (\w{1,})" + ")", where (\w{1,}) occurs m times
```

How can I do that? I know that it will look roughly like

`re.sub(\w{1,}){2,}, inputstring, "(" + however many instances of (\w{1,}) the pattern was able to match + "))`

How do I express, in regex, that the pattern was matched m times? (So that I can do the replace, surrounded by parenthesis).

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you're trying to match? In the abstract, it's a bit hard to grasp, and easy to go down the wrong track. Thanks!

Comment: @zk81 I have a string like 'n n bacon n'. I want to find all times that this occurs in a text. So 'I love bacon strips' would fit the pattern. I want to group the 'n n' bit so that I get (I love) bacon (strips)

Comment: How do you know the end of one fragment and the beginning of another? For instance, `I love bacon strips and I love raw bacon too`. Where does the `and` fit: with the first match, or with the second match?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you writing one regex to create the pattern for another regex? Which one are you asking for help with? Also, why are you using `\w{1,}` rather than the more concise `\w+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're writing one regex to produce another regex. That is, you're using a regex replacement to build the pattern for a regex search. Your input includes some kind of wildcard value (e.g. `"n"`) which you need to replace to create the search pattern. In the search pattern, adjacent wildcard values should be combined into a single capturing group (so `"n n bacon n"` will give two capturing groups, one for the first two words and one more for the last). I think you can do this if you first capture all the adjacent wildcards, then substitute for the individual instances within the larger group.

Here's code that does that:

```
import re

def make_pattern(template, wildcard="n"):
    replacement_pattern = r"\b{0}\b(?:\s+{0}\b)*".format(wildcard)
    def replacement_func(match):
        return "(" + re.sub(wildcard, r"\w+", match.group()) + ")"
    return re.sub(replacement_pattern, replacement_func, template)
```

The `\b` escape sequences in `replacement_pattern` are necessary to prevent occurrences of `wildcard` from being treated as such if they are part of some larger word (like the `"n"` at the end of `"bacon"`). The closure `replacement_func` uses an additional regex replacement to swap out the wildcards, while preserving the spacing between them (so a template like `"n  n n   n"` will match differently than `"n n n n"`). I suppose you could do a regular string replacement (with `str.replace`) instead, if you wanted to. I just couldn't resist three levels of regexing in one solution.

Here's an example run:

```
>>> make_pattern("n n bacon n")
'(\\w+\\s+\\w+) bacon (\\w+)'
>>> re.findall(make_pattern("n n bacon n"), "spam spam eggs bacon and spam")
[('spam eggs', 'and')]
```

Comment: works great. out of curiosity, why is replacement function defined within make_pattern? Because it is a helper function that should not be exposed to global namespace? Is that a common python pattern? Does it have a name?

Comment: In this specific case, it's necessary for `replacement_func` to be defined within `make_pattern` because it is a "closure". That means it accesses variables (specifically, the `wildcard` parameter) from the enclosing scope. Closures aren't used too often in Python, but it's nice to know how they work in case you do find one useful. A more common way to write nested functions is to use a `lambda` expression directly in the place you're using the function (e.g. in the call to `re.sub`). I didn't do that here because the line would have been really long and there was no obvious place to wrap it.